# Secure transmission of file from client to a server

Tags: php, android, cryptography

I'm uploading an encrypted file from Android phone to a server and decrypting the same file in the server side.

Client: Used HTTP post to send file to a server
Server: PHP
Encryption: Triple DES

I hard coded the keys and iv in both the client and server side. Is there any idea how to use the keys and iv so that the transmission is highly secured?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If android encrypts the file immediately prior to transmitting it and the server decrypts it on receipt, then you should just use SSL/TLS/HTTPS.

Hardcoding either the key or the IV is horribly bad practice. If you hardcode the key in an application, anyone who can get the binary has the key and can read the message. If you hardcode the IV, even people who do not have the key can potentially do something( IV's can be public, but they MUST be random)

Answer (score 3):

No. If you hardcode a symmetric key into a client application that runs on untrusted devices, it's practically no encryption at all. An attacker can just extract the key from his application, and decrypt all other transmissions.

Just use https with a single trusted root public key corresponding to your server.

Comment: No. I'm not an android user. But either there is a built in library, or you can use BouncyCastle.

Comment: @CodesInChaos If android device was rooted, hacker can access to specific file. Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951805/protected-document-viewer

Comment: @Mr.Hyde SSL/TLS is useful if you want to achieve security, but not for DRM.